# Having a separate search microservice or integrate it inside the microservice having the data to be searched after?

Tags: java, web-services, web, architecture, microservices

I am currently learning microservices and working on a project and i got the following question:

Let's say I have the following service: Item Service.

Item service will work with creating different items in a mongodb DB. I will also want to have a search function in my app and I would implement it by using Meilisearch since it also features support for geolocation searches and it's pretty neat overall.

I don't know which of the following approaches I should follow:

1. Integrate all of this inside my Item Service

2.1) Have a separate service for the search functionality but in this case the search service should somehow interact with the database of Item Service. Should search service make direct calls to the DB item service is using? ( Basically 2 services on one DB, but one only reads one only writes)

2.2) Have a separate service for the search functionality and also a different DB ( I'd need to somehow keep the info in sync in the both databases and also I don't know if it's ok since I'd have duplicate data)

I'd appreciate suggestions on this since I am really new to Microservices.
Thanks!

I did not try anything yet, I don't know which approach to follow basically

Comment: A key ingredient to help you choose a path is understanding the search use cases. Here are some questions that should help shape the problem: You mentioned geolocation, but what other kinds of search do you expect to support? Free text search? Across how many properties? And how many data types? Are items the only entity returned by the search? How many records are we expecting to have? Would users type something into a search bar, or would they use a filter form?

Comment: Free text search would be cool, hoped Meilisearch would allow me to do that. Searches should be made upon the titles of the items ( or the tags <- I will use an image classifier which will automatically classify my images with some tags). Yeah only items should be returned by the search, geolocation is pretty important as I'll kinda render those locations on a map. Yeah i wanted users to type smth into a searchbar which is why I wanted to go for a search engine like meilisearch. I just dont know if making a secondary DB and somehow try to implement CQRS with that db would be a good idea or not

Comment: The kind of features you described seem to point to something that would be better served by a search engine database. Especially as the scale and complexity of queries might grow. But if it's a small project, you may want to avoid growing the project's tech stack. There is no real 'right' solution, and it's a matter of tradeoffs. Better query performance, more scalable, and flexible? Go with a search engine DB. Leaner tech stack, fewer components, but less scalable? Go with the DB you have. Rob Conklin's answer already gives you some comparison points between the two options.

Comment: Think I'll go with the separate microservice with Meilisearch option then. Thanks a bunch for all the advice.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56775778/19917972 all filtering should be done via query to the DB. Now for the search option you can cache lets say names of entities you will provide search for. And then on button click you issue the query and get it. It all depends how efficient you need it to be and what are you searching for. But the best is combination of cache and db querying

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you're telling me to not have a separate DB but actually make all the queries in my main DB and somehow cache them for the Meilisearch to use afterwards? Hope I'm correct, if not don't hesitate to correct me. Yet my question remains. In this case should I also integrate Meilisearch in my Item Service and follow the approach you told me to ( so basically not have a separate search service)?

Answer (score 0):

Search is very often a cross-cutting concern across multiple databases/services.  Implementing an effective search-engine often requires back-end loading and composition of multiple entities into a single flattened view for high-speed searches.  Databases are notoriously VERY bad at this, and are not optimized for searching.  Most databases have some patched-on layer which does help with creating things like inverted indexes, but they are generally a poor substitute for a real stand-alone search engine, but definitely comes with convenience of not having to have a separate data-store and dealing with streaming changes to that other data store.

Regardless, look at your database, look at the available search engines, explore what your cloud/hosting provider has available.  There is probably going to be a product that is your lowest barrier-to-entry that you should start with that will give you what you want pretty efficiently.

Also, I'd be astonished if it fit neatly into a single "item" service.  As soon as you want to search for items in a user's order history, or some other sort of cross-entity concern, you will want to have a consolidated search index.

Answer (score 0):

Your concerns are another way to say 'when to use the CQRS (command query responsibility segregation) pattern'.

I ll add the [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820748/when-to-use-the-cqrs-design-pattern) here, but you can do some more research on your own. From my POV, if it is just some learning project, then you dont expect high traffic, so you dont have the scalability concern. So go for the easiest option which is a search inside current microservice. If you want to learn CQRS then obviously go for it.

Regarding 2.1, in general avoid accessing DBs of a microservice from outside its scope. So avoid creating a service that can access the items db from outside items-microservice. This complexes things a lot in large scale, many teams etc. Think that different teams might work on each microservice in a real world example and how messy this could get...

Comment: I appreciate it a lot. It's basically a bigger project for my final year project. Won't be used irl obviously but I'd love to have some scalability as my teacher would appreciate it.  Again thanks for the advice

Comment: i get that you dont have any experience on designing systems and you dont want to learn everything just for this assignment, but you need to first understand that usually there isnt a golden rule. you pick your design + technology stack based on the requirements.

For your items service i see 2 options. One is a microservice which does all the interaction with the DB and the other is CQRS. whichever one u pick, u just need to document the decision right. and this is not just regarding the numbers (read/writes per second) but also have a look at ACID cause u need to handle race conditions etc

Comment: By CQRS you mean to make another DB for my search microservice and somehow try to keep it in sync with my main db by sending events or smth through a rabbitmq pipe or something? ( Still learning rabbitmq and microservices stuff so please forgive my technical language).  The search DB would ofc be only for reads mostly, but there would be writes and deletes as well since i need to keep it in sync with the first db if i understand correctly. I could try to do this but idk what troubles I might encounter. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: yeah, so i guess you need to spend more time on reading about CQRS and you need to decide if you want to add this extra time for the learning curve. As I said the solution design is a matter of decisions and this one is something you ll face in your professional career as well (using a new tech). For your specific question, the 2 databases will be kept in sync behind the scenes, not on application level. Again this is something for you to research cause there are different solutions for different requirements. And you ll have to sacrifice something in ACID if you want to go with CQRS..

Comment: i dont want to lead you to any decisions, but another thing i would do in your case is to check what Meilisearch suggests, since this is your main tool. From some brief search i did, i see that they mostly go with a simple solution of 1 db. app stores directly at it but then queries through Meilisearch

Comment: Thanks for all the info. It's true I don't have much knowledge about CQRS I learnt a little about it for a project I had to do for faculty where we basically had a monolith and kinda split the commands and queries, but in our project we only used one DB following our teacher's advice, as in this case I'm talking about microservices and potentially different DB's so of course there is a little bit of confusion. Trying my best to pick up on a solution as quick as possible as I need to get to the actual work ( still in the phases of deciding the architecture)